# Python - Find sum of all even numbers in 2 Dimensional List

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is:

Given   a   "two-dimensional    list"   of  integers    – that  is, a   list    where   each
value   in  it  is  a   list    of  integers    – find  all the even    numbers and sum them together.

The first one is my first attempt where I seem to have successfully made it work with 1 list. Then I try to make it work with a 2D list, and this code gives me an error 'int object is not subscriptible' and I think it's to do with my while statement. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
def sum_even(xss):
    result = 0
    for item in xss:
        if item % 2 == 0:
            result = result + item
    return result
ans = sum_even([4,8])
print (ans)

def sum_even(xss):
    result = 0
    n = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while xss[i][0] in xss:
        if xss[i][0] % 2 == 0:
            result = result + xss [i][0]
        while xss[0][j] in xss:
            if xss[0][j] % 2 == 0:
                result = result +xss[0][j]
    i +=1   
    return result
ans = sum_even([4,8])
print (ans)
```

Comment: Please don't deface your question after you've gotten an answer. People have donated their valuable time and expertise to help you.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues with your code. The simplest would be using 
 [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) with a nested conditional generator expression:

```
def sum_even(xss):
    return sum(x for sub_lst in xss for x in sub_lst if not x % 2)
```

The scopes of the nested for-expressions seem counter-intuitive at times. This is roughly equivalent to:

```
def sum_even(xss):
    result = 0
    for sub_lst in xss:
        for x in sub_lst:
            if not x % 2:
                result += x
    return result
```

For arbitrarily nested lists of integers, you would have to use recursion:

```
def sum_even(xss):
    if isinstance(xss, int):
        return (not xss % 2) * xss  # the bool expr is neatly coerced to 1 or 0 ;)
    return sum(sum_even(sub) for sub in xss)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
even_numbers = sum(i for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(first_list) if i%2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. It works with any dimension list (not just 2):

```
list2d=[[1,2],[2,3,4]]
result=sum([int(elem) for elem in str(list2d).replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',') if not int(elem)%2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> reduce(lambda s,x:s+x,[i for l in a for i in l if not i%2],0)
12
```

without itertools and using just list comprehension.

Much simpler thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga, much simpler version

```
>>> a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
>>> sum([i for l in a for i in l if not i%2])
20
```

Comment: use `sum` instead of `reduce`

Answer (score 1):

Specifically this error means you are trying to use an `int` as if it were a `list`.

The cause for this is that your second `sum_even` function was built to handle 2D lists, but you are using it on a 1D list (`[4,8]`) instead of on a 2D list (`[[4],[8]]`).

Despite of that, your code has another error:

```
def sum_even(xss):
    result = 0
    n = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while xss[i][0] in xss:
        if xss[i][0] % 2 == 0:
            result = result + xss [i][0]
        while xss[0][j] in xss:
            if xss[0][j] % 2 == 0:
                result = result +xss[0][j]
    i +=1   
    #there is no update for j
    return result
```

In python, for statements dont use indexes with the iterator. The result is something more like a phrase:

For each `1d_list` within the 2D list `xss`, check the `elements`. If the `element` is even, add it to `result`.

```
def sum_even(xss):
    result = 0
    for 1d_list in xss:
        for element in 1d_list:
            if element%2 == 0:
                result = result + element
    return result
```

In this way you dont make any assumption on the length of the lists (each 1D sublist may have a different size).